# display only value, which have more, than 2 the same value in other column

Tags: sql

I want to display only books, which have more, than 2 authors. I am receiving data from database called books.The columns are 
id
author
title
cover
isbn

```
select author,
count(*) as title_count 
from books 
group by author 
having Count(*) > 2
```

I am getting the list of authors who has more than 2 books in database.
if use

```
select title,count(*) as author_count from books 
group by title
having Count(*) > 2;
```

I am getting the list of books with the count of how many time certain author is in database.

I want display author and title of the book, but only incase that author has more than 2 books in database.

For example, this is the list of authors with more than 2 books in database:
A. C. Bhaktivedanta Swami Prabhupada 4
A. J. Hill 3
A. Manette Ansay 3
Adrian Plass 4
Agatha Christie 19
now I need to add another column TITLE

Comment: Please make this a complete question by adding sample data.

Comment: You edited and changed the requirement. You even posted as your code the code from the answer you received for the original question. This is enough to downvote.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty simple question which can be done using `Having`

```
select title,count(*) as author_count from books 
group by title
having Count(*) > 2;
```

**UPDATE**

```
   select title,author,count(*) as author_count from books 
    group by title,author
    having Count(*) > 2;
```

Comment: thanks, I had query, which gave me opposite list to authors, not to books. But i need to display both Author and Title, thanks for help

Comment: just add author to it

Comment: i tried it, getting error #1055 - Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'library.books.author' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: can you try again? the group by did not have author

Comment: ```select author, count(*) as name_count from books group by author having Count(*) > 2```                                                                                                      I am receiving 430 results                                                                                                    ``` select title,author,count(*) as author_count from books 
    group by title,author
    having Count(*) > 2``` I am getting only 12 results,

Comment: I am expecting exactly 2411 rows

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions to get the detail:

```
select b.*
from (select b.*, count(*) over (partition by title) as num_authors
      from books b
     ) b
where num_authors > 2
order by title;
```

You can also use `group_concat()` to get the authors with their list of books:

```
select author, group_concat(title separator ' | ')
from books
group by author
having count(*) > 2;
```

Comment: thanks, I am receiving an error:                                                                                    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near                                        
'(partition by title) as num_authors
      from books b
     ) b
where num_auth' at line 2

Comment: @NKU . . . Window functions have been part of MySQL since version 8.  You might be using an older version.

Comment: yours query displays only one book from each author, who has > 2 in database. I want display all books, from author who has > 2 books in database. I tried everything else, even Subquery, nothing so far worked out

Comment: SOLVED Like, I took 1st query to build new table, then used ```SELECT books.author, books.title FROM books WHERE EXISTS (SELECT duplicates.author FROM duplicates WHERE books.author = duplicates.author) ORDER BY `author` ASC
```